# Useful scripts for Sikuli

Tags: autohotkey, script

Thanks to Lifehacker I came across [Sikuli](http://groups.csail.mit.edu/uid/sikuli/) which is described as:

> Sikuli is a visual technology to
>   search and automate graphical user
>   interfaces (GUI) using images
>   (screenshots). The first release of
>   Sikuli contains Sikuli Script, a
>   visual scripting API for Jython, and
>   Sikuli IDE, an integrated development
>   environment for writing visual scripts
>   with screenshots easily. Sikuli Script
>   automates anything you see on the
>   screen without internal API's support.
>   You can programmatically control a web
>   page, a desktop application running on
>   Windows/Linux/Mac OS X, or even an
>   iphone application running in an
>   emulator.

As this looks very promising, perhaps complementary to [AutoHotKey I'm curious what scripts you guys will come up with](https://superuser.com/questions/7271/most-useful-autohotkey-scripts). Especially since this program is portable and could solve "simple" Super User problems.

> Example script from their
>   documentation:
>
> - setThrowException(True)
> - setAutoWaitTimeout(10000)
> - switchApp("System Preferences.app")
> - click([image])
> - click([image])
> - click([image])
> - click([image])
> - wait([image])
> - type("192.168.0.1\t")
> - type("255.255.255.0\t")
> - type("192.168.0.254\t")
> - click([image])

Comment: It looks interesting, but at same time not very "reactive". Something great probably for really repetitive actions for which you can't use keyboard shortcuts on a certain way. But the fact that you really *feel* the time during which it tries to find the correct area on screen for each action is a bit of a dealbreaker for me, as I feel I would go faster scanning the screen and clicking by myself. So for some complicated and long task that you repeat often, sure. But it has to be something you can't do faster than this program, for me.

Comment: Well I would use it more to automate tasks for my grandma, like connecting to Teamviewer or something silly like that

Comment: true, that's a good example of use.

Comment: @Gnoupi go add a nice script, so at least I have an answer... :(

Answer (score 3):

I just found somce new examples on [their blog](http://sikuli.org/blog/). Sikuli seems extremely useful for GUI controlled software, such as anti-virus software

[image]

or controlling your OS, such as changing themes and power settings

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Basically you can do everything with Sikuli and maybe even more that you can do with scripts or Terminal.

This could be useful for basic user, but if you can do the same thing with a simple script, what would be the utility ? (in the way that a normal user won't make the script itself but rather ask someone who knows more than him to give him a fully functional script)

So if you're looking for useful scripts *especially for Sikuli*, any useful Automator, AppleScript, shell scripts or whatever languages ported to Sikuli.

Some examples, scripts for :

- Changing User-Agent in Safari
- Setting up a proxy server or turning it off
- Locking the screen
- Changing screen resolution if you have several monitors
- Changing to graphic card (for MacBook Pro with double cards)
- Activating or changing order of network interfaces
- Turning bluetooth on and connecting to iPhone for network tethering
- Choosing the boot volume

I tried to choose actions that should not be easy to do without Sikuli.

Comment: It's exactly what I'm looking for: show me a useful script that would help out a normal user or give me a good idea on what script to make :P Not everything can be automated when working in a GUI (though John T will prove me wrong)

Comment: I don't know if these examples are enough or if you need more "complex" ones.

Comment: There are also useful/funny examples on the official blog : http://blog.sikuli.org/ . The first one (bottom of the page) is nice example !